# Last Inserted Row info without Auto-Incrementing PK

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've got a number of tables that "share" a single auto-incrementing primary key - this is accomplished via a trigger on insert which looks like this:

```
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO master (time) VALUES (NOW());
        SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END
```

This produces the PK for the just inserted row. This does, however, create the problem that I can't seem to figure out what that ID was. last_insert_id obviously returns nothing as the above statement wasn't executed on what's considered "the current connection".

Is there a way to access the most recently inserted row on a connection without an auto-incrementing primary key?

Update: As a temporary(?) measure I've removed the trigger and now generate the ID by making the insert to `master` within my model. Just seems like it would be nicer if I could somehow return the value that the trigger set.

Comment: So how will you identify which row has been inserted, if you dont have the identifier (PK)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc does say, "For stored functions and triggers that change the [LAST_INSERT_ID] value, the value is restored when the function or trigger ends, so following statements do not see a changed value."

Try a stored procedure, which can do your two INSERTS and return the assigned ID.

Or, give up on doing things the "Oracle way", drink the MySql Kool-Aid, and just use an auto-incrementing id on the table.

Comment: if you read the original question you'd see why I'm not using an auto incrementing ID -- the auto incrementing ID is on a master table and shared by 3 other tables. It seemed cleaner to not have to insert to the "id generator" table in the PHP code, but its doable, as per my edit. I may try the stored procedure route, but my experience there is limited.

Comment: I read your original question and saw that you were sharing the master table, ala Oracle.  I don't believe (though I cannot verify now that you've edited it), that you did not, however, explain WHY you were doing such a thing.  Big difference.